# Formatting issue for app preview video uploaded to App Store Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload a video preview to the Apple App Store Connect website, with no luck. I can get the videos to upload but an unhelpful error message appears providing no clue as to WHY the upload was successful.

Here's what the Quicktime video inspector window shows for my video:

[image: Quicktime movie inspector window]

Here is what happens on App Store Connect when I upload:

[image: App Store Connect error message on movie upload]

Checkoff list:

- Framerate at or below 30 FPS
- Bitrate between 10-12 MBits
- Size: 886x1920
- Audio: AAC 44100 Stereo

What am I missing? I've blown a day messing around with Apple's amateur-hour website trying to upload the videos, I'm close to giving up.

Comment: OK, gave up after exporting through iMovie also failed to upload. Unfortunately I don't have more days to spare doing this. Absolutely no feedback on the webpage indicating WHY the save failed. It's a poorly developed website. If I were the PM at Apple in charge of this I would be embarrassed.

Comment: OK, I'm hearing from others that Apple currently has an issue with App Preview uploads to their website (i.e. issue in the past week). Developer support now at Apple is now not very good so no way to confirm this.

Comment: Size is incorrect? 654 x 1417 is not a known size. Check out https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev4e413fcb8

Comment: That’s incorrect, the inspector window is stating the current displayed size on my screen, above that is the actual size of the video.

Comment: What's the length of the video?

Comment: 29 seconds in length

Comment: If you could upload the video somewhere, it would be easier to analyze.

Comment: that I can't do for commercial reasons. From what I currently understand, the site is broken for app preview uploads or Apple has changed the accepted specs.

Comment: Not really. Have been uploading countless of different app previews for multiple apps.

Comment: Then I don't know what the issue is. Are you uploading H264 or ProRes?

Comment: mp4/H264 Try to upload https://www.dropbox.com/s/yzq9o6e6ziaoa2d/iphone65-en-US-1-portrait.mp4?dl=0 with latest Safari (non-beta)

Comment: Thanks appreciated - uploads without error but after pressing the save button on the web page is gives: Your app preview is in the wrong format. For more information, see the Developer Help. - same as before

Comment: Another developer is also having problems saving previews that uploaded/saved without problems previously. I do believe this is a website issue

Comment: Make sure to delete all other app previews and screenshots. Contact App Store Connect Developer support for better debugging.

Comment: Thanks Max - will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response following reporting the issue to Apple:

> We are aware of the issue and looking into it further

This sort of thing is so avoidable, if only Apple had put the resources into developing the App Store Connect website to process videos in different formats.

Comment: I got a message today from Apple that they've fixed the issue - I've tested and it does work but it's not completely fixed. Still not saving when it's in the Media Manager screen. Really flaky interface, Apple should fire the project manager.